# Query a player's friends

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table called PlayerFriends to model a many to many relationship.

The PlayerFriends table has PlayerFriendPlayerID and PlayerFriendFriendID.They are foreign keys.

a Player from the Players table has a PlayerName field.

I would like to select all the PlayerName of all friends for player 'pid'.

I have a query right now that can get me all the friends:

```
SELECT * FROM PlayerFriends WHERE PlayerFriends.PlayerFriendPlayerID = pid;
```

But how can I instead select the friend's PlayerName?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this with a simple `Join`:

```
Select  P.PlayerName
From    PlayerFriends   F
Join    Players         P On F.PlayerFriendFriendId = P.PlayerId
Where   F.PlayerFriendPlayerId = pid
```

Answer (score 2):

Try :

```
SELECT C.PlayerName 
FROM Players AS A 
    JOIN PlayerFriends AS B ON B.PlayerId=A.id
    JOIN Players AS C ON B.PlayerFriendPlayerID=C.id
WHERE A.id=pid
```

Comment: Still wrong there is no need to join again players table and you should join players with friends id